# Multiple $filter in OData query

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, filter, project-server, odata, expand

Here is my OData query:

```
https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=Id eq guid'xxxx'&$select=Id,Name,StartDate&$expand=Tasks&$select=Tasks/Id,Tasks/Name
```

I also want to add `$filter` on the expanded object, this is what I have tried:

```
https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=Id eq guid'xxxx'&$select=Id,Name,StartDate&$expand=Tasks($filter=Name eq 'xyz')&$select=Tasks/Id,Tasks/Name


https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=Id eq guid'xxxx'&$select=Id,Name,StartDate&$expand=Tasks&$select=Tasks/Id,Tasks/Name&($filter=Name eq 'xyz')


https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$filter=Id eq guid'xxxx'&$select=Id,Name,StartDate&$expand=Tasks&$filter=Name eq 'xyz'&$select=Tasks/Id,Tasks/Name
```

None of the above work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#sec_QueryingCollections

> The same system query option MUST NOT be specified more than once for
> any resource.

So, you can't use `$select` twice on the same level. Instead, pass the `$select` into expanded entity using semicolon to separate it from `$filter` expression.

> /Projects?$filter=Id eq
> guid'xxxx'&$select=Id,Name,StartDate&$expand=Tasks($filter=Name eq
> 'xyz';$select=Id,Name)